# Develop app for personal use on mac OS X

Tags: macos

I want to build an APP for OS X to simplify my work, so it's for personal use only.
I wanted to know, since I searched everywhere and I saw a lot of different answers, if it's possible to develop the app without the program they have ($99). 
This App is not to be uploaded on the AppStore.

Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You can develop any app you like - it's your computer! What language do you want to use? And what costs $9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can develop personal applications - even public ones. Digital trusted signing and distribution costs the $99 subscription.

To download the Xcode IDE you need a registered developer account at Apple. For this account no fees have to be paid.

Comment: I don't believe you need a registered developer account at Apple - you can simply go to the AppStore and download Xcode for free.

Comment: At some point it was necessary to mark an Apple ID as a developer account. Possible that since programming is for everyone now that they lifted this restriction.